# How to get the concrete class name as a string?

Tags: python

I want to avoid calling a lot of `isinstance()` functions, so I'm looking for a way to get the concrete class name for an instance variable as a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of a question that got me here.

I'm reading the "Concrete Objects Layer" documentation for Python 3. That documentation describes C-level mappings with types that are lower-level than the regular class name. So, for example, the documentation describes a "PyLongObject".

I'd like to know how to get this low-level name given an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

```
 instance.__class__.__name__
```

example:

```
>>> class A():
    pass
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__class__.__name__
'A'
```

Comment: I prefer: `type(instance).__name__`

Comment: What if you don't want to instantiate the class? can you just get the name of the class? (without the object)

Comment: For class A, use the following: `A.__name__`

Comment: Is there a way to get it with the import path? For example, `str(type(foo)) == "<class 'never.gonna.give.youup'>"` but `type(foo).__name__ == "youup"`. How do I get `never.gonna.give.youup`?

Comment: For path you can use type(foo).__module__

Answer (score 35):

```
<object>.__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 9):

you can also create a dict with the classes themselves as keys, not necessarily the classnames

```
typefunc={
    int:lambda x: x*2,
    str:lambda s:'(*(%s)*)'%s
}

def transform (param):
    print typefunc[type(param)](param)

transform (1)
>>> 2
transform ("hi")
>>> (*(hi)*)
```

here `typefunc` is a dict that maps a function for each type. `transform` gets that function and applies it to the parameter.

of course, it would be much better to use 'real' OOP

Comment: +1. An 'is' test on the class object itself will be quicker than strings and won't fall over with two different classes called the same thing.

Comment: Sadly, this falls flat on subclasses, but +1 for the hint to "real" OOP and polymorphism.