# Python equivalent to Java's MyClass.class.getName()

Tags: java, python

In Java, MyClass.class.getName() (assuming a class named 'MyClass') serves a purpose of getting the name of 'MyClass' even if MyClass is renamed, while hardcoding "MyClass" in a string will become unreliable.

Note: there is no instance available - this is crucial to the question.

e.g.,
Java:

```
String unreliableName = "MyClass"; //will be incorrect if 'MyClass' is renamed
String reliableName = MyClass.class.getName(); //if 'MyClass' is renamed, 'reliableName' will still be correct
```

C# has 'nameof', which serves a similar purpose for a much wider range of constructs.

In Python, how would you do this?
I think we can rule out the 'type' function since we don't have an instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the concrete class name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521502/how-to-get-the-concrete-class-name-as-a-string)

Comment: @Lars: No - there is no instance - that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: The question was closed without carefully reading it - I want the class name *without an instance*.

Comment: The question i linked does not imply that an object is needed. There are good comments on the accepted answer. If you want to get the name of a class called A you can use `A.__name__`.

Comment: @Lars: Doesn't "instance.__class__.__name__" require an instance?

Comment: @Lars: Ok - I see the comment hidden deep in there about A.__name__.  I don't think this link directly answers the question - it might be worth a separate question.

Comment: Yes, but you can just use the \__name\__ variable of the class type

Comment: @Lars: Could you post the answer? I think anyone looking for this is going to find it a lot easier if it's a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of a class, you can use the `__name__` variable of the class you want to get the name of.

e.g. `A.__name__` for a class called A

For reference: [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__)